# What is the C++ equivalent of Objective C "@class MyClassName"?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, import, include

In the headers of my Objective-C classes, I use `@class MyClassName` to be able to use the `MyClassName` object in a defined class.

In Objective-C, there's a difference between `@class MyClassName` and `#import MyClassName.h`?

Does such a difference exist in C++?

The C++ equivalent of `#import "MyClassName.h"` is `#include "MyClassName.h"`.

What is the C++ equivalent of Objective-C `@class MyClassName` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forward declaration in c++ looks similar - just remove '@' from obj-c variant:

```
class MyClassName;
```

Answer (score 1):

yes there is such distinction in C++ too. In C++ it is called forward declaration. You forward declare a class like:

```
class ClassName;
```

Just to add extra info, forward declaration is used when you are using a class before it is declared. The compiler will be bit lenient and wont throw error but it still need the full class declaration later.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ equivalent of `#import "MyClassName.h`" is not `#include "MyClassName.h"`

"#import" also prevent cyclic inclusion of files for which in c++ we normally do

```
#ifdef __abc.h__
#define __abc.h__

//actual code


#endif
```